# Getting cell value from GridView after Edit button is clicked Round 2

Tags: c#, asp.net

I posted this not long ago, but no I have to update the question to ensure I get the right answer.

I have a GridView. I need to update an SQL table based on values from the GridView. 
When a user clicks the default EDIT button on the GridView, changes whatever they change, then hits UPDATE. Here is where I run into problems. I've tried multiple OnRowEditing, OnRowUpdating, OnRowUpdate as the button control.

Here is the code I use to that.

```
protected void gvReviewedPolicy_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {
        DateTime dateTime = DateTime.Now;

        //GridViewRow editRow = gvReviewedPolicy.Rows[gvReviewedPolicy.EditIndex];
        //string Emailed = editRow.Cells[7].Text;
        //string UniqClient = editRow.Cells[1].Text;
        //string UniqPolicy = editRow.Cells[3].Text;

        string UniqClient = gvReviewedPolicy.SelectedRow.Cells[2].Text;
        string UniqPolicy = gvReviewedPolicy.SelectedRow.Cells[3].Text;
        //string Email = Emailed.ToString();
        //string dt = dateTime.ToString();
        //string Up = UniqClient.ToString();
        MessageBox.Show(UniqClient);
        MessageBox.Show(UniqPolicy);
        //MessageBox.Show(dt);

        string query = "UPDATE [Reviewed_Renewal_Policy] SET [DateUpdated] = @dateTime where ([UniqClient] = @UniqClient) AND ([UniqPolicy] = @UniqPolicy)";

        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=GTU-BDE01;Initial Catalog=TestDB;Integrated Security=True"))
        {
            using (SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand(query, conn))
            {
                comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UniqClient", UniqClient);
                comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UniqPolicy", UniqPolicy);
                //comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Emailed", Emailed);
                comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dateTime", dateTime);
                conn.Open();
                comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
                conn.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

I have some commented out because I was trying different things. However, the code that says

```
GridViewRow editRow = gvReviewedPolicy.Rows[gvReviewedPolicy.EditIndex];
    string Emailed = editRow.Cells[7].Text;
    string UniqClient = editRow.Cells[1].Text;
    string UniqPolicy = editRow.Cells[3].Text;
```

It's supposed to access the values in those cells when UPDATE button is pushed. However, using MessageBox.Show , comes back blank.

Anyone have any idea how I can capture those values after hitting Edit, then the default UPDATE button?

Comment: Have a look at [this tutorial](http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial/editing-data-using-asp-net-gridview-control). It covers all the basics of GridView editing and updating.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to make that Winforms Datagrid usable for "write through" in the past, by implementing an DataGridView subclass (this allows you to access everything) but since immutable databases and queue transactions came into view, my Access-flavour DataGrid did not survive modern paradigm. Nowadays I tend to support ASP.NET MVC 5 to "edit" databases.

Anyway have you considered to connect a DataSource ? You don't have to access cells.. you can update using a connection like

private SqlDataAdapter daGrid = new SqlDataAdapter();

and this type of approach, you will have to fill in the details yourself, the complete code consists of several classes and is too large to post,

```
    protected void dataGridView1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        DataGridView dgv = (DataGridView)sender;
        /// .. perform actions according to keyboard events ..
        /// .. for example below one ..
    }

    public override void UpdateAfterEditGrid(DataSet ds, DataGridView dataGridView1, bool DoRestoreCursor)
    {
    if (daGrid != null)
    {
        if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Closed) conn.Open();
        dataGridView1.EndEdit();
        try
        {
            if (ds == null)
            {
                //DataGridView dgv = dataGridView1;
                //Console.WriteLine("Go datasource update .. " + dgv[cColumnIndex, cRowIndex].Value);
                daGrid.Update((DataTable)dataGridView1.DataSource);
            }
            else daGrid.Update(ds);
            LoadGridRestoreCursor(dataGridView1, DoRestoreCursor);
        }
        catch { ErrorReporting.ErrorMessage("== cannot update this content =="); }
    }
}
```